# Sequentially Combining Three Lists Created with Regular Expressions - Python

Tags: python, list, expression

I have a text file I am reading with three regular expressions. I'd like to combine each item from each regex search line by line and print them out using the same format as the last line below. I just cannot get the loop right to combine everything.

Sample Text from three different sources(you can see info is sometimes missing and other times presented in different formats:

1. Bond Name             O/F    C/F   Cpn    MTR FICO CAL WALB  1mCPR  60+   CE
   CWL 2004-6 2A5          0.95   0.09  L+39    4         49  200   4     28.62 47.69%
2. Bond Name        O/F    C/F   Cpn  FICO CAL WALB   60+   Notes             Offer
   CSMC 06-9 7A1   25.00  12.01  L+45  727  26  577  33.29  FLT,AS,0.0%       50-00
3. Type     CUSIP    Bond Name      Term    Offer   Structure
   PRIME    17312KAB8    CMSI 07-5 1A2      7/7         92.50     LCF

```
import re

string = open("cusip.txt")
read_string = string.read()

cusip_reg_exp = re.compile('\s[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}\s')
cusip_result = cusip_reg_exp.findall(read_string)

bond_name_reg_exp = re.compile('\s[A-Z]{3,5}\s[0-9]{4}\D{1,3}\S{1,3}\s{1,2}\w{1,3}')
bond_name_result = bond_name_reg_exp.findall(read_string)

bond_price_name_reg_ex = re.compile('[$]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2}[-]{1}[0-9]{2}')
bond_price_result = bond_price_name_reg_ex.findall(read_string)

print(cusip_result[0],bond_name_result[0],bond_price_result[0])
```

Comment: This entire program can probably be expressed in under 5 lines with no regex. Care to share the input file format?

Comment: Not sure I understand "input file format?" This comes from an email pasted to a text file. I would like it to be an email read and saved as text files, but I am still figuring that one out.

Comment: yeah just post the first few lines of cusip.txt if it's not sensitive data.

Comment: Looking at the sample input, it looks like your records will become out of sync on output, because not every record has a cusip_reg_exp match. I was worried this might happen...

Comment: @dadashek If either of the responses answered your question it would be nice if you would accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`zip` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) or [`itertools.izip` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip):

```
for i, j, k in zip(cusip_result, bond_name_result, bond_price_result):
    print i, j, k
```

Depending on the format of the file, the [`csv`  *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module might be helpful too (instead of using regular expressions to extract the content).

You could also iterate over each line and extract the relevant information per line.

Comment: +1, I was trying to do it with a list comprehension and it wasn't working :grouse: :grumble:

Comment: it's totally doable with a list comp :)

Comment: @Reno I know, that's what makes it so irritating :^\

Answer (score 1):

If all of those lists will be the same length, you can concatenate each corresponding entry (delimited by a space) to create a list of the combined strings, and then concatenate those (delimited by a newline) to create the displayed list of results.  I decided to do it with some list comprehension wizardry (no for loops!).

```
print '\n'.join([' '.join([cusip_item, bond_name_item, bond_price_item]) for (cusip_item, bond_name_item, bond_price_item) in zip(cusip_result, bond_name_result, bond_price_result)])
```

Hopefully that serves your needs.  If not, I'm sure there will be several other interpretations to this question :)

Edit: I realize it's a bit long, but you could shorten the variable names perhaps.  Alternatively (or perhaps, in addition), you could define zip(cusip_result, bond_name_result, bond_price_result) prior to the comprehension.  I just can't help myself with these things though, I love hot python one liners!

Comment: +1 that's what I was trying to do but my brain wasn't functioning properly :^}